# Running multiple elasticsearch instances

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to setup 2 Elasticsearch instances:

- one for kibana logs (my separate application will throw logs at it)
- one for search for my production application

My plan is to create a separate folders with elasticsearch in them. They dont talk to each other which means they are separate databases and if one goes down, the other still runs. Is this good solution or should I use only one elasticsearch folder with muliple elasticsearch.yaml configuration files? What is the best practice for multiple elasticsearch instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice is to NOT run two Elasticsearch instances on the SAME server.

Your production search will probably need a lot of ram to work fast and stay responsive. You don't want your logging system interfere with that.